How to save button checked state with Tabulator custom radio headerMenu
I created a Tabulator (v5.5) popup headerMenu that contains two radio buttons.  It initializes and displays the way I want and when I select one of the radio buttons to do my action, the action works correctly but when I display the headerMenu again it always comes back with the same radio option checked as what I initialized it with and not the last one selected.
I would like it to show the option that was last clicked on while it was being displayed.  It seems as if a new headerMenu is constantly getting created but not by calling the label function I specified.  It seems like it stores the original one it created (with the original html) and then keeps bringing it back when requested.  Is there a way to force a new one to be created using the functions call for the label?  Or maybe there's a better way to set this up in general.
The headerMenu is initialized like this (in column setup):
columns:[
  {
    title:"", // just show the ... button
    // other fields left out for clarity
    headerMenu: [
      {
        label: this.getRadioHtml(false),
        action: $.proxy(this.subsetFilterClicked, this)
      },
      {
        label: this.getRadioHtml(true),
        action: $.proxy(this.allFilterClicked, this)
      }
    ]
  }
]

Here are the functions:
// this only gets called once per menu item at initialization and then never again
getRadioHtml: function (isAllItem)
{
  var radioHtml = null;
  var isCheckedStr = "";
  if (isAllItem)
  {
    // this is set to true on startup
    if (this.isShowAll)
    {
      isCheckedStr = "checked";
    }
    radioHtml = "<input id='allRadioButton' type='radio' name='nameFilter' value='all' " + isCheckedStr + "> All";
  }
  else
  {
    if (!this.isShowAll)
    {
      isCheckedStr = "checked";
    }
    radioHtml = "<input id='subsetRadioButton' type='radio'  name='nameFilter' value='subset' " + isCheckedStr + ">MySubset";
  }
  return radioHtml;
}
...
subsetFilterClicked: function (e, column)
{
  // setting these actually changes the radio button but only while it's displayed
  //   the next time it pops up, the value goes back to how it was initialized
  $('#allRadioButton').prop('checked', false);
  // maybe redundant due to the radio group
  $('#subsetRadioButton').prop('checked', true);
  // filter function call goes here
},
allFilterClicked: function (e, column)
{
  $('#allRadioButton').prop('checked', true);
  $('#subsetRadioButton').prop('checked', false);
  // clear filter function goes here
}

